# Error: getVisibleRowCount not a function

Tags: sapui5

I try to get the count of visible rows of a table in a SAPUI5 application.

But the following code doesn't work as aspected:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("paramTable").getItems();
var rowCount  = oTable.getVisibleRowCount();
```

The error message in the console messages that the code in the second line was not a function.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which type of table implementation are you using?

Comment: I mean the standard table : 

<Table id="paramTable" items="{/callbackData}" width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin">

Comment: `sap.m.Table` does not have `getVisibleRowCount` method

Comment: oh sorry - i haven't read carefully...